# Populating a DIV with external HTML on hover with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, hover, external

I am quite new to Jquery, and I am having trouble with the .load(); function. 
I am building a site for a restaurant, and when the user hovers over the item on the menu (menuitem class) , I want to load the appropriate data into a div with ID iteminfo from the HTML file i'm using, menusrc.html.

from reading the APIs, I learned you can use the .load(); function to bring in external HTML and use the second argument to specify the ID of the content you want to load. I am still quite new, so I am unsure as to proper syntax when doing more complex functions such as these.

here is the relevant HTML

```
 <li id="a1" class="menuitem"><span class="num">A1: </span>Gỏi cuốn <em>3.95</em></li>
 <div id="iteminfo">   </div>
```

and my Jquery

```
$(".menuitem").hover(
function () {
$("#iteminfo").load("menusrc.html #" + this.id);
},
function () {
$("#iteminfo").empty();
});
```

the external html file is in the same directory and looks like this for testing purposes

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="a1">THIS IS THE INFO FOR A1</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In my head, this function should work as so:
when the mouse enters an item of class menuItem, load the HTML with the same ID as the menuItem into the div with ID itemInfo. when the mouse leaves the menuItem, it should empty the div.

maybe i'm using .hover wrong or should be using .mouseenter or something, but i havent been able to get .load to work at all, so I think my mistake might be there.

thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: Your external file needs to be an HTML page at best, not a fragment

Comment: Okay, i have changed it to a full webpage more or less, and it still isnt loading anything into the div.


i have updated the OP with the new HTML

Comment: This seems like an utterly waste of ajax. If this is what you intend to do, and not just a really simple example, you should consider your options. This approach will load content with ajax every time someone mouses over that element, and if the content is static, just showing and hiding it would be a lot better IMO. And do not include a doctype, head, body etc. in the file you're getting the content from, unless you filter that content, as that would just lead to invalid markup.

Comment: @adeneo, there's not enough information to infer which method it is gonna be better IMHO. The number of elements at stake is unknown

Comment: @Alexander - loading content with ajax on hover events is generally a bad idea, the more content, the worse it gets IMO ?

Comment: @adeneo, an amazingly slow huge static page is generally worse at user's eyes. Don't get me wrong I agree that the show/hide strategy is generally better than AJAX. But, your conclusion was simply too harsh

Comment: there will be close to 50 items on the menu I think, each with a description, picture, price, etc. quite a bit of data. do you think there is a more efficient way to load the menu item information into the DIV using Jquery and external HTML, im trying to stay away from databases. the site is for a small local business and they really cant be troubled with it.

Comment: The user would need to hover his mouse and wait for the AJAX request to complete? Seems better if you did the request once at the beginning of your script and store it to be appended / removed from the DOM on hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `#` before the id in the load function, and you have an extra set of parenthesis. Remove those.

try:

`$("#iteminfo").load("menusrc.html #" + this.id);`

Comment: Okay, i actually had already lost the extra parenthesis. I added the # as instructed. still not working. :S

Comment: Have you confirmed that your hover event is firing by putting something simple in it? Is that hover code inside `$document.ready()`?